# Tdengine syntax order issue

Tags: tdengine

TDengine sql error when executing aggregate query:

```
select avg(value) as gauge from table1 where ts >= now - 30d and ts <= now group by cluster interval(30d)
```

```
DB error: syntax error near "interval(30d);" (0.000552s)
```

What are the syntax errors in this sql?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found in TDengine documentation: https://www.taosdata.com/docs/en/v2.0/taos-sql
Listed the order of **select** conditional statements.

```
SELECT select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    FROM {tb_name_list}
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [SESSION(ts_col, tol_val)]
    [STATE_WINDOW(col)]
    [INTERVAL(interval_val [, interval_offset]) [SLIDING sliding_val]]
    [FILL(fill_mod_and_val)]
    [GROUP BY col_list]
    [ORDER BY col_list { DESC | ASC }]
    [SLIMIT limit_val [SOFFSET offset_val]]
    [LIMIT limit_val [OFFSET offset_val]]
    [>> export_file];
```

So the **Group by** should be put after **Interval**, here is the correct sql:

```
select avg(value) as gauge from table1 where ts >= now - 30d and ts <= now interval(30d) group by cluster
```